# Android: how to recreate same button (View) in another activity

Tags: android

I am new to android and I'am writing my first app with androidstudio.

I have two activities: the first has a bunch of buttons, all sharing the same onClick() event, which starts the second activity. The second activity has a single button. Both layouts are designed with the interactive GUI editor.

I want the button of the second activity to appear similar (but not identical) to the one in the first activity, which was touched. After much research, I succeeded in identifying the *drawableLeft* of the source button, and pass its name to the second activity, which then sets it to the target button. However, I find this method too limiting and complicated, considering that probably I will need to pass other data like color and so on.

This is what I am doing now: buttons in the first activity have their tag set to the name of the resource for drawableLeft. On the onClick() event, the tag is read and sent to the second activity via putExtra(). The second activity receives the name of the resource, obtains a resourceID via getResources().getIdentifier, creates the drawable via getDrawable(), and finally sets it to the destination via setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicsBounds().

Problems are: 1) I have to set the *tag* property redundantly for every button in activity 1; 2) I also want to copy other properties like color and who knows what else more - should I stuff everything in the tag?

Finally the question: is there a more straightforward way to get GUI attributes and forward them to a second activity?

Thank you,
linuxfan

Comment: Why don't you try creating an `xml` layout of your button. Then you can use the same layout file in any `activity` with `LayoutInflater`

Comment: Thank you, I thought this, but didn't say in order to keep the question brief. It seems to me viable, but a little complicated. If there are no simpler ways, I will do so.

Comment: `public class CustomButton extends Button`... Start from there

Comment: That is the kind of things I don't want to do: I don't want to extend anything... I want to use a normal button, using a comfortable GUI editor, and read and set properties dynamically.

Comment: Problem is that by using the standard button and repeating elements, instead of creating custom components, you're going to have a lot of repeated code and a potential maintenance nightmare further down the line. If you create your custom buttons correctly too, they'll show up fine in the GUI editor. Spend a bit of time learning how to make custom controls at the beginning, and it'll save you so much time further down the line.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to achieve your goal.Create a seperate xml file for your button.

```
<Button 
   android:id="@+id/your_btn"
   android:layout_width="50dp"
   android:layout_height="50dp"
   android:padding="10dp"/>
```

Now what you can do is on your Activity

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.yourActivityLayout);
   //this ViewGroup should be inside yourActivityLayout xml file
    ViewGroup group = findViewById(R.id.where_you_want_your_btn);

    getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.your_btn_layout,group,false);
```

}

or

You can create Fragment or and use it on your activity the process is almost same as above.

```
 private void addFragment(Fragment fragment){

    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragment_container,fragment);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
}
```

just create a frament with the layout you want to repeat and call addFragment(new YourFragment()) it from you activity;
since you are new get more detail on Click [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html)!

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I see two problems. First: if inflating an XML always creates a new View, then I would like to do a different thing, i.e. "merge" a few properties/attributes. Second problem, related or same, is that I would like to create the second-activity layout the normal way with the androidstudio GUI editor, and only after, in code, get and set selected properties (more...)

Comment: (...more) In your XML example, width and height are fixed; but I am not sure I want the buttons in the two activities have the same width/height: only the same drawableLeft, and/or color, or whatever I choose.

It is true that I can always "retouch" using code, but then probably the interactive GUI editor is useless - I can do everything I want in code... apart from getting attributes from an activity and transfer it to the second... :-)

Answer (score 1):

I found a way, a dirty way, but it works. So i reply to myself.
There can be inconsistencies in this reply, I am new to this problem and I am still experimenting.

As said by Dhrumil Patel, Michael Dodd and Ujjwal Mainali, the way to go is to extract the visual infos to be shared, and put them somewhere easily accessible. For every button needed in activity 1, I created a layout resource like this:

"file: tbt_turndown.xml":

```
<merge>
<Button xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:tag="tbt_turndown"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Turn down"
    android:drawableLeft="@android:drawable/arrow_down_float"
    android:drawablePadding="8dp"
    />
</merge>
```

In my understanding, this file should only contain the "appearance" of the button, and no info about its positioning in the final layout.

Then, the normal layout file for activity 1 INCLUDEs the buttons defined above:

"file: buttons_setup.xml":

```
<LinearLayout
    ...
    <TextView
        ...
    <GridLayout
        ...
        <include layout="@layout/tbt_turndown"
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_row="1"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:onClick="butClick" />

        <include layout="@layout/tbt_turnup"
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_row="1"
            android:layout_column="2"
            android:onClick="butClick"
            />
        ...
    ...
    ...
```

Doing so, strange things happen in androidstudio GUI editor: many properties disappear, for example onClick and many others, and androidstudio complains that "layout_row" is ignored because no "layout_width" is specified. I went ahead by editing xml file by hand, an the app in the device runs ok.

All these buttons share a single event handler, which is the following:

```
public void butClick(View w) {
    // obtain info from the sender of this event
    // the tag contains the name of the resource used to build this View
    String myres = ((Button) w).getTag().toString();

    Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, settAButton.class);
    myIntent.putExtra("myres", myres);

    startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
}
```

The new started activity must show the selected button and let the user configure it. The user preferences will be stored somewhere in non-volatile memory. On start, this activity does the following:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_settAButton);

    // obtain info from calling activity
    Bundle bundle=getIntent().getExtras();
    Integer tbtID = this.getResources().getIdentifier( bundle.getString("myres"), "layout", this.getPackageName());

    // inflate the resource (a Button) somewhere
    ViewGroup group = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.llyMyBt);
    getLayoutInflater().inflate(tbtID, group, true);

    // get a reference to the newly created button
    Button mybut = (Button) group.getChildAt(group.getChildCount()-1);

    // now extract the wanted info - for now, just the drawableLeft
    Drawable draw = mybut.getCompoundDrawables()[0];

    // and assign it to destination
    ((Button) findViewById(R.id.btExample)).setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(draw, null, null, null);
}
```

Here, I had a problem with inflating the button layout; my first try was to NOT assign the newly created button to any container, but at runtime android insisted that, using "merge" in the layout file, it was mandatory to put the button into a container. Oh well...

I suppose that, finally, the newly created button should be removed, but it is invisible anyway, so this is not important.

EDIT: no, the button IS visible. I had to delete it.