# Why LayoutInflater.inflate returns the root passed as parameter?

Tags: android, android-layout

I tried, in code, to inflate a view into a container and to get at the same time a reference to my inflated View (a Button). So the code was like this:

```
Button mybut = (Button) getLayoutInflater().inflate(resID, lyMain, true);
```

But this doesn't work: the returned result is not what I expected. Reading the doc at https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html, I've found that:

`(inflate...returns)... The root View of the inflated hierarchy. If root was supplied and attachToRoot is true, this is root; otherwise it is the root of the inflated XML file.`

Now the stupid question: why this method should return something I already know (when I pass a root and "true" to attach to it)? It is more probable that I need a reference to the just inflated View, rather than to the root/container I passed to the method.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is indeed odd. But doing the following will have the exact same result, but will actually capture the inflated layout:

```
Button mybut = (Button) getLayoutInflater().inflate(resID, lyMain, false);
lyMain.addView(mybut);
```

So it does require an extra line of code, but that seems like a minor inconvenience to me compared to having to call `findViewById` or `getView(index)`.

The documentation explains the difference fairly well, but I guess you've already read that:

> root: Optional view to be the parent of the generated hierarchy (if attachToRoot is true), or else simply an object that provides a set of LayoutParams values for root of the returned hierarchy (if attachToRoot is false.)

Comment: Yes, I read the doc and yes, I did like you says - with two statements. I asked because I wanted to be sure about this "strange" return: it could allow some other construct which I'm not aware of.

Comment: I think @natario's explanation is most likely why it actually happens.

Answer (score 3):

I think the reason of this design choice is that your layout resource *might not have a root itself*.

That is the case with `<merge>` layouts, e.g.

```
<merge>
    <View />
    <Button />
</merge>
```

This can be inflated in a parent ViewGroup, but can’t be represented as a whole with a single View instance. Returning the parent ViewGroup seems the only choice here.

Comment: Actually I used merge, see my question+reply: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41302370/android-how-to-recreate-same-button-view-in-another-activity  I will try to pass root and _false_ to inflate().

Comment: I think it will throw an exception. The <merge> tag can contain multiple childs. Which child are you expecting to get? See my example. There’s no reason why it should return Button.

Comment: True. But it is non-sense. In my case there is just a button, and anyway the error is on "mybut = ...inflate(..., group, **false**)". The error is "merge can only be used with root and attach=true". inflate() wants a root, then wants to attach the new view to the root, and then refuses to give me a reference. So the only way I found to get a reference is the one you see in the post, and I find it ugly.

Comment: @linuxfan well, using a `<merge>` tag with just a single child inside is also nonsensical. I suggest you read more about that tag, because using `<merge><Button></merge>` is exactly like using only `<Button>`. The *only* difference is that if you use `<Button>` you wouldn’t have the issue described here.

Comment: In my first try I didn't use merge, but androidstudio design editor gave problems, and it seemed to me it was necessary. Now I deleted it, and actually it works. The designer is still unhappy, but is "workable". About the returned reference by inflate(), I think that returning the first inflated view would be smarter than returning something I already have..., especially when the docs say that **it can** return a reference to the inflated view. Let's say that, normally, I do know what I am going to inflate! Thanks and regards.